# Need some advice with my ActionListener in Java

Tags: java, actionlistener, parseint

I'm currently working on a program in Java(beginner) and I need some assistance getting my buttons to actually work in the GUI. I copied my code to the bottom of the post. I've written my ActionEvents method and feel like I'm getting closer with my if-statements but I'm still stumped. I tried to implement "result.setText("Sum of given two numbers is "+ res);" and make my buttons work but I just don't know where to go next.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonActionOne extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton add, subtract, multiply, divide;
    JLabel operand1, operand2, display;
    JTextField op1, op2, result;
    Integer num1, num2;
    
    public ButtonActionOne() {
        setSize(250, 400);
        setTitle("Button Action");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        operand1 = new JLabel("Operand 1:");
        operand2 = new JLabel("Operand 2:");
        display = new JLabel("Output:");
        add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(this);
        subtract = new JButton("Subtract");
        subtract.addActionListener(this);
        multiply = new JButton("Multiply");
        multiply.addActionListener(this);
        divide = new JButton("Divide");
        divide.addActionListener(this);
        result = new JTextField(50);
        op1 = new JTextField(10);
        op1.getText();
        op1.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        op2 = new JTextField(10);
        op2.getText();
        op2.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(op2.getText());
        
        add(operand1);
        add(op1);
        add(operand2);
        add(op2);
        add(add);
        add(subtract);
        add(multiply);
        add(divide);
        add(display);
        add(result);
        
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ButtonActionOne();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object o = ae.getSource();
        if(o == add) {
            result.setText("The sum of the given numbers is " );
            System.out.println(result);
        } 
        if(o == subtract) {
        System.out.println();
    } if(o == multiply)
        System.out.println();
    if(o == divide) {
        System.out.println();
    }
        
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors when bringing up the GUI, but I don't know how or when to use my getText. I also declared two integers and used the "parseInt" but I still don't much no how to proceed to make my buttons work! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You have only one actionPerformed method (only one listener) but bind it to all the UI objects: The add/subtract buttons and the JTextFields, which means it even gets invoked when a user performs his input and presses enter.

So you will have to check why the method was called. Your actionPerformed method should look like this. It is not complete, but I think you get the point.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    try {
        if (ae.getSource()==add) {
            o1 = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText());
            o2 = Integer.parseInt(op3.getText());
            result.setText(String.format("%d + %d = %d", o1, o2, o1+o2));
        }
        if (ae.getSource()==subtract) {
            o1 = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText());
            o2 = Integer.parseInt(op3.getText());
            result.setText(String.format("%d - %d = %d", o1, o2, o1-o2));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.setText("Could not calculate");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```